# Excel macro to highlight common values between two different sheets

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, microsoft-excel-2003, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm having list of account numbers(AA, AAB, AAC, ADC) in column A in  sheet 1 and also I'm having some common account number in sheet 2 (AAB,ADC)which is  already available in sheet 1. Now i need a macro to highlight only those  common account number  in sheet 1.

Comment: Use `VLOOKUP(...)` from either, looking up values in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Format the values on Sheet1 using Conditional Formatting. A condition like `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A;A1)>0` should do the job.